# Does After Delete trigger result in Mutating table?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I read somewhere that solution to mutating table is to use After Delete trigger. Is this correct?

Comment: A link to the somewhere that you read this might be useful.

Answer (score 7):

No it is not correct, and an AFTER DELETE, FOR EACH ROW trigger can result in the "Table is mutating" error.  The solution is not to perform an operation against the same table in a FOR EACH ROW trigger defined on that table.  Tom Kyte has documented a method for avoiding this issue [here on AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551198119097816936).